# How can I fix this error and this vulnerability

Tags: node.js

There is a bug in the code that leads to a vulnerability by using this code in the command line

```
socket.emit("broadcasting", {
            cmd: "new"
        });
```

> result from
> 0|server  | TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

And this as well

```
socket.emit("broadcasting", {
            cmd: "send"
        });
```

> result from
> 0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Can you fix this code?

```
socket.on("broadcasting", (data) => {
        if (typeof data != "object") {
            return;
        }

         if(UserInfo[socket.id]){
            if (data.cmd == "new") {
                if (UserInfo[socket.id].rep >= SiteSetting["miclikes"]) {
                    io.to(UserInfo[socket.id].idroom).emit("broadcasting", { cmd: "new", it: data.it, user:socket.id });
                    socket.emit("broadcasting", { cmd: "new", it: data.it });
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][data.it].id = socket.id;
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][data.it].ev = true;
                } else {
                    socket.emit("msg", {
                        cmd: "not",
                        data: {
                            topic: "",
                            force: 1,
                            msg: SiteSetting["miclikes"] + " " + "عدد الايكات المطلوبة للمايك",
                            user: "",
                        },
                    });
                }
            } else if (data.cmd == "send") {
                const myfr = JSON.parse(data.mj);
                if (myfr.type == "new-ice-candidate") {
                    socket.to(myfr["target"]).emit("broadcasting", {
                        cmd: "send",
                        msgString: JSON.stringify({
                            type: myfr["type"],
                            it: myfr["it"],
                            target: myfr["target"],
                            user: socket.id,
                            candidate: myfr["candidate"],
                        }),
                    
                    });
                
                } else if (myfr.type == "video-offer") {
                    socket.to(myfr["target"]).broadcast.emit("broadcasting", {
                        cmd: "send",
                        msgString: JSON.stringify({
                            type: myfr["type"],
                            it: myfr["it"],
                            target: myfr["target"],
                            sdp: myfr["sdp"],
                            user: socket.id,
                        }),
                    });
                } else if (myfr["type"] == "hang-up") {
                    // if(myfr["target"] == socket.id || VerRoomsOwner(UserInfo[socket.id].power)){
                        if( PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][myfr["it"]]){
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][myfr["it"]].id = "";
                    PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][myfr["it"]].ev = false;
                    io.to(UserInfo[socket.id].idroom).emit("broadcasting", { cmd: "send", msgString: data.mj });
                    };
                } else if (myfr["type"] == "video-answer") {
                    socket.to(myfr["target"]).emit("broadcasting", {
                        cmd: "send",
                        msgString: JSON.stringify({
                            type: myfr["type"],
                            it: myfr["it"],
                            target: myfr["target"],
                            sdp: myfr["sdp"],
                            user: socket.id,
                        }),
                    });
                } else {
                    io.to(UserInfo[socket.id].idroom).emit("broadcasting", { cmd: "send", msgString: data.mj });
                }
            }
        }
      });
```

I tried a lot to fix it and it didn't work

Comment: i mean...validate your data?

Comment: FYI, `JSON.parse('undefined')` yields `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`  That should be a pretty good clue as to what's happening.  Also `PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][data.it].id` seems like a long shot in terms of relying on user data being valid.  I'm not surprised it's missing.  `PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][myfr["it"]].id` seems like an equally long long-shot.

Comment: I tried a lot to deal with it and did not find a result. Can the code be modified and fixed?

Comment: FYI, saying "I tried a lot to fix it" without saying *what* you tried, diminishes the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a packet with invalid data, you can just ignore it. You SHOULD ignore it, or maybe block the sender. So you need to check if you have invalid data.

```
         if(UserInfo[socket.id]){
            if (data.cmd == "new") {
                if (!PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][data.it]) return; // INVALID
                if (UserInfo[socket.id].rep >= SiteSetting["miclikes"]) {
                   ....
                }
            } else if (data.cmd == "send") {
                try {
                   const myfr = JSON.parse(data.mj);
                } catch (e) {
                   // INVALID? Or possibly a normal string to send to all users?
                   return;
                }
                if (typeof myfr !== 'object') return;

                // you may need additional check for each case below...
                if (myfr.type == "new-ice-candidate") {
                ...
                } else if (myfr.type == "video-offer") {
                    ...
                } else if (myfr["type"] == "hang-up") {
                    ...
                } else if (myfr["type"] == "video-answer") {
                   ...
                } else {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possibly even could check that: `PeerRoom?.[UserInfo?.[socket?.id]?.idroom]?.[data?.it])` is truthy.  It's such a large number of things that have to be valid, it's *all* worth validating.

Comment: yes, but `data` was already checked and everything else is static data, not data from the packet, so likely can be assumed to be valid.  Otherwise, that's a lot of extra code to execute for every packet for no reason

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me
                if (!PeerRoom[UserInfo[socket.id].idroom][data.it]) return;

Comment: The second one I fixed by this code
 if (!data["mj"]) {
                    return;
               }